# diagonal line in two axis graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Please, is there any way of drawing a diagonal line which links the average of the varaible measured on the righ axis (UM Consumer sentiment index) and the other one measured on the left axis (US GDP)? 
Below is the code that I used.

Many thanks

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (16,8))

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(us_consumer_index['Index'])
ax2.plot(us_gdp.loc['1978-01-01':,:])

plt.title('Services PMI vs. Real GDP Growth 2008 - 2018')
plt.xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax1.set_ylabel('UM Consumer sentiment Index')
ax2.set_ylabel('% GDP Grwoth')
ax1.legend()
ax2.legend(loc = 2)
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "links". If you can provide an image showing what your plot looks like and a clearer indication of what you're trying to achieve, that would be very helpful. It sounds like you're trying to generate a ratio of the two (although you'd need an additional axis in that case in all likelihood)

Comment: Perhaps a [mcve] too?